# How to access root-folder with Thunar?

Tags: permissions, xfce, thunar, ubuntu-studio, gksu

I would like to access root-folder with Thunar but the system won't let me, even if I have setup a root in a terminal window.

What's the way to access the root-folder (with write access) in Thunar (GUI)?
Does it work out of the box without installation of additionals?

I need to add drivers for a USB 3.0 PCIe card and the files have to be placed in the target kernel (e.g. \linux-2.6.28)

The answers to this topic I read at askubuntu.com require some other apps to be installed, like Nautilus or gksu, which are not present at my Ubuntu Studio 15 installation and I don't want them to install.

I've been able to define a root user's password and operate as root in a terminal window, but this won't let me access root-directory with Thunar.

Comment: Start Thunar with sudo like `sudo -H thunar`.

Answer (score 0):

Start **thunar**  as root by invoking the command
    `gksudo thunar` but if
    `sudo thunar`

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean with "root-folder" is the filesystem root (/), then you can do it using the command `sudo thunar /`.